# How can I add pager to the comments of advanced forum in drupal 7?

Tags: forms, comments, paging

I use the drupal 7 core forum with advanced forum module.

This works perfectly except the forum topic page show only post comments what number is defined on the content type, and no pager on the comments, therefore the users can't jump to the next few comments.

My question: how can I add pager (first, prev, next, last, etc.) to the advanced forum post comments?

I didn't found any solution until yet.

Comment: can you check comments per page setting at admin/structure/types/manage/forum/edit#edit-comment

Comment: yes, I know this. But if I set 10, then the forum show the last ten comments, and the users can't jump to the next few comments except if go back to the forum topic page and select an another comment page, or type the page number in the address bar.

Comment: I searching for solution to place pager on the forum comments

Answer (score -2):

In your style directory, you should have a *.topic-header.tpl.php file. Make sure the following is where you want the paging to display:

```
<?php print($pager); ?>
```

Then, in *sites/all/modules/advanced_forum/includes/theme.inc*

Approximately line 446:

```
  pager_default_initialize($variables['node']->comment_count, variable_get('comment_default_per_page_forum'));
  $variables['pager'] = theme('pager');
```